# Go to specific tab from other page

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation, bottom-navigation-bar

I am using DefaultTabController and BottomNavigationBar to show my tabs. When I want to go to homepage from a different page. For e.g, from SubmitForm() page, I will call navigation back to a specific tab index. In this case, I want to go to SearchFacilities() so the index will be 1. I will do Get.to(() => HomePage(selectedPage: 1). However, it still leads me to index: 0 (Locations()) page,  and not index: 1 (SearchFacilities()) page.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.selectedPage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int selectedPage;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final screens = [
    Locations(),
    SearchFacilities(),
    SearchCommodities(),
    Settings(),
  ];
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  void _updateIndex(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = value;
    });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      initialIndex: widget.selectedPage,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: screens[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          // fixedColor: Colors.black,
          // type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: _updateIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Locations",
                icon: _currentIndex == 0
                    ? SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/building.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )
                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/buildinggrey.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Facilities",
                icon: _currentIndex == 1
                    ? SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/repair.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )
                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/repairgrey.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Commodities",
                icon: _currentIndex == 2
                    ? SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/commodities.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )
                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/commoditiesgrey.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: "Settings",
                icon: _currentIndex == 3
                    ? SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/settingsgrey.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )
                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/settingsgrey.svg',
                        width: screenWidth(context) / 8,
                      )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've taken the parameter `selectedPage` in `HomePage` as :

`HomePage(selectedPage: 1)`

But, you're not doing anything with that `selectedPage`.

Change your `_HomePageState` as follows :

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final screens = [
    Locations(),
    SearchFacilities(),
    SearchCommodities(),
    Settings(),
  ];
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  void _updateIndex(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _currentIndex = widget.selectedPage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

Comment: I have noticed and realized that mistake, I have solved it by replacing all _currentIndex to widget.selectedPage. Appreciate your help!